# java class- setX circle method

Tags: java, class, methods

I am having problems with my homework assignment. I created a Circle class but i'm getting some errors while using the setX and setY methods. that i don't know how to fix. My code is below. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle {
private Point origin;
private double radius;

public Circle(Point o, double r)
{
    setOrigin(o);
    setRadius(r);
}

public Circle(double xValue, double yValue, double r)
{
    origin.setX(xValue);
    origin.setY(yValue);
    setRadius(r);
}

public Circle()
{
    setX(0.0);
    setY(0.0);
    setRadius(1);
}

public Circle(Circle c)
{
    setOrigin(c.getOrigin());
    setRadius(c.getRadius());
}

Point getOrigin()
{
    return new Point(origin);
}

public void setOrigin(Point p)
{
    origin.setX(p.getX());
    origin.setY(p.getY());
}

public void setX(double value)
{
    origin.setX(value);
}

public double getX()
{
    return origin.getX();
}

public void setY(double value)
{
    origin.setY(value);
}

public double getY()
{
    return origin.getY();
}

public void setRadius(double value)
{
    radius = value;
}

public double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

public double getArea()
{
    return (radius * radius) * Math.PI;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "(" + origin.getX() + ", " + origin.getY() + ", " + radius             + ")";
}

public boolean equals(Circle c)
{
    if (origin.getX() == c.getX() && origin.getY() == c.getY() &&
    getRadius() == c.getRadius())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean doesOverlap(Circle oC)
{
    double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(getX() - oC.getX(), 2) +    Math.pow(getY()-oC.getY(), 2)));

    if ((radius + oC.radius) > distance)
    {
        return true;    
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Point {
private double x;
private double y;

public Point(double xValue, double yValue)
{
    x = xValue;
    y = yValue;
}

public Point(Point p) {
    this(p.x, p.y);
}

public Point() {
    this(0, 0);
}

public void setX(double xValue)
{
    x = xValue;
}

public double getX()
{
    return x;
}

public void setY(double xValue)
{
    y = xValue;
}

public double getY()
{
    return y;
}

public boolean equals(Point otherPoint)
{
    return (this.x == otherPoint.x) && (this.y == otherPoint.y);
}

public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors, but my first guess is a null pointer exception as I don't see you ever instantiating origin

Comment: @Sean Speaks the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) of Point. There are no such methods like `setX(...)`

Additionally, I think you should initialize it especially in your second and third constructor

```
public Circle(double xValue, double yValue, double r){...}
public Circle(){...}
```

via

```
origin = new Point();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method setX(double) is undefined for the type Point

 at Circle.setX(Circle.java:46)
 at Circle.<init>(Circle.java:22)
 at MyCircleTester.main(MyCircleTester.java:5)

Comment: THis is what that method should look like but i'm still getting errors there too.                                                           public Circle(double xValue, double yValue, double r)
 {
  origin = new Point(xValue,yValue);
  setRadius(r);
 }

Comment: I think the problem i was having was the the point class wasn't in the same src folder as the Circle class.